Export table of content from Google scholar PDF reader
It has been a long-standing problem for me to read a long PDF without an outline. A few months ago, Google posted its genius PDF reader (Chrome extension) that can automatically generate outlines for papers. Is there a way to export the generated outline?

Right-click anywhere on the PDF viewer > Inspect > Ctrl + Shift + C > Hover over the element that contains the entire TOC > Right-click on element within the Inspect interface > Copy > Head over to https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer > Paste and Run/View
